# Form a single image from multiple blocks without getting the chessboard pattern

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using the Hopfield neural network to process a 400x400 satellite image.

However due to hardware issues I'm unable to process the entire image as a single image. Hence I've divided it into blocks of `50x50 each`.

However after processing these blocks and combining them to form a single image, the borders of the blocks show up. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Chessboard pattern is a consequence of image encoding. You can avoid this by using uncoded images. If you provide your source code I might be able to tell more detail.

Comment: It would also be good if you posted an example to give people something to work with (i.e. an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: I was reading over the adaptive histogram equalization in matlab ( http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/adapthisteq.html?refresh=true ) and it process an image in tiles but then it does bicubic interpolation on the boundaries to smooth the transitions. Maybe you can try that method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run the same algorithm on your image twice. do it once normally, then slightly offset your blocks and do it again. then average the two together you can still see the "checkerboard" but it's not as noticeable. You may have to play with the offset to get more desirable results. Also you an probably make the code smarter so that it doens't change the image size, but this was just a quick proof of concept.

I used histogram equalization as my algorithm. You can see the "avg of blocks" looks less "chessboard-like". I even did a difference between the whole image processing and the blocks. you can see the difference is much smaller between the avg and the whole image than for either of the two blocks

[image]
[image]
    offset = 25;

```
fun = @(block_struct) histeq(block_struct.data)

%processes entire image, this is the baseline
a = histeq(im);

%does original block processing
b = blockproc(im,[125,125],fun);

%offsets the blocks and does processing again, please notice this
%changes the size of the image
c = blockproc(im(offset:end,offset:end),[125,125],fun);

%averages the two together (using the smaller image)
d= b(offset:end,offset:end)*.5+.5*c;

%the original image shows what processing the entire image loo
figure(1)
subplot(3,2,1:2);imshow(im);title('original')
subplot(3,2,3);imshow(a);title('operation on entire image')
subplot(3,2,4);imshow(d);title('avg of blocks')
subplot(3,2,5);imshow(b);title('blocks')
subplot(3,2,6);imshow(c);title('offset block')


figure(2);suptitle('difference between operation on entire image and block images')
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(a);title('operation on entire image')
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(abs(a(offset:end,offset:end)-d));title('avg of blocks')
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(abs(a-b));title('blocks')
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(abs(a(offset:end,offset:end)-c));title('offset block')
```